# How to generate a pdf file from the information of a form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, pdf

I am creating a project for a job in the university and my project will be created in angular 4 in which a form will be filled and then using this information in conjunction with other texts that I have stored I wish that a pdf letter will be generated .
In the end I have to upload the project to firebase

How could I do this in Angular?
Some idea of the structure of steps that could follow

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in the end, it has to be uploaded to Firebase. I'd suggest you don't do it in Angular / the browser directly, rather a Cloud Function for Firebase.

Check out the Cloud Functions samples repo https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples and something like [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) to get started.

Comment: thank you for your quick response I must use a framework for the exercise, you think this solution would be fine:
Use angular to define all the areas of the web application which you should have:
• A form to complete the details of the persons (such as first and last name, etc.) (which will be stored in a database created in firebase)
• A window to select additional texts to the certificate that will be generated and which will use the data previously filled in to complete the certificate and generate it in pdf through a button (I would save the texts also in the bd of fire